# Aligning columns in beamer with a list

Tags: beamer, lists, vertical-alignment

I often run into a problem with `beamer`. I have a picture on the left and an `itemize` environment on the right. However the itemized text appears at the very bottom and is often cut off. I then need to do some massive `\vspace{-x pt}` to align it. Is there a better way?

Here's an example:

```
\begin{columns}
\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{2ENQ-A.png}
\column{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
        \vspace{-130pt}
    \item<1-> 345, 453 and 420 are all associated with cancer and increased lipid activity.
    \item<1-> E453Q may disrupt interaction with p85 regulatory subunit.
    \item<1-> N345K and C420R associated with oncogenic gain of function. Constitutively activate AKT and TOR-mediated signaling.

\end{itemize}
```

Comment: In your code, an `\end{columns}` is missing. Also, if you add `\column{.35\textwidth}` before `\includegraphics` the two columns will be center-aligned by default. You can use the options `[t]`, `[T]`, or `[b]` to change the alignment style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I use columns environment for alignment at the top (you may repalce the [t], by [c] for centering).

```
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{5cm}
    \begin{figure}
         \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{2ENQ-A.png}
    \end{figure}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{5cm}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> 345, 453 and 420 are all associated with cancer and increased lipid activity.
        \item<1-> E453Q may disrupt interaction with p85 regulatory subunit.
        \item<1-> N345K and C420R associated with oncogenic gain of function. Constitutively activate AKT and TOR-mediated signaling.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

Then you may need to play around with the scale and the size of the two columns before reaching what you want. Maybe some lighter code exists for this purpose but this one has never failed me yet.